# JAXB Unmarshall XML tag con el mismo nombre

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

recibo un xml en un servicio web y lo convierto a objeto todos los valores me los asigna correctamente pero el xml tiene 2 tags con el mismo nombre y no puedo asignar los valores en los tag con el nombre status alguien sabe como hacerlo :?

Este es el xml que recibo, como pueden ver hay un tag llamado status y otro status con un objeto dentro, he intentado hacerlo de varias maneras pero solo logro que alguno de los tags reciba el valor que quiero.

```xml
`<message>
    <availableEquipment>
        <id appCode="MASTER"></id>
        <createDate>04/05/2019</createDate>
        <equipment>
            <id type='Dollys' appCode="MASTER">265</id>
            <code>DLY-265</code>
            <serialNumber></serialNumber>
            <name>Dolly de 500 toneladas</name>
            <iave></iave>
            <cost>720</cost>
            <status>active</status>
            <engineNumber></engineNumber>
            <brand>Nissan</brand>
            <model>2019</model>
            <litreCapacity></litreCapacity>
            <carryingCapacity></carryingCapacity>
            <mileage>25</mileage>
            <porpouse>
                <id></id>
                <name></name>
                <description></description>
            </porpouse>
            <dimensions>
                <depth id="MASTER.FONDO">1.200</depth>
                <height id="MASTER.ALTO"></height>
                <width id="MASTER.ANCHO"></width>
            </dimensions>
            <doors>
                <left></left>
                <rigth></rigth>
                <back></back>
                <front></front>
            </doors>
            <billOfLading></billOfLading>
            <palletsQty></palletsQty>
            <useAccesory>S</useAccesory>
            <fuelLoad>N</fuelLoad>
            <status>
                <id appCode="MASTER/TRATE">2</id>
                <type>MASTER TRACTO_STATUS</type>
                <name>Regresa a CEDIS</name>
                <value>2</value>
            </status>
            <km>
                <local></local>
                <foreign></foreign>
            </km>
        </equipment>
        <cedis>
            <id appCode="MASTER" name=""></id>
            <name></name>
            <stateCode></stateCode>
        </cedis>
        <comments>
            <id></id>
            <text></text>
        </comments>
    </availableEquipment>
</message>
```

Este es mi bean de equipment pero no se como debería de quedar para que me funcionase.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id","code","serialNumber","name","iave","cost","statuss","engineNumber","brand","model",
"litreCapacity","carryingCapacity","mileage","porpouse","dimensions","doors","billOfLading",
"palletsQty","useAccesory","fuelLoad","status","km"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Equipment {
    private IdTagEquipment id;
    private String code;
    private String serialNumber;
    private String name;
    private String iave;
    private Double cost;
    @XmlElement(name = "status") //No se si esto me funcionará
    private String statuss;
    private String engineNumber;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private Double litreCapacity;
    private Double carryingCapacity;
    private int mileage;
    private Porpouse porpouse;
    private Dimensions dimensions;
    private Doors doors;
    private String billOfLading;
    private String palletsQty;
    private String useAccesory;
    private String fuelLoad;
    private Status status;
    private Km km;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu caso puedes solucionarlo usando MOXy

```
@XmlPath("status[1]/text()")
private String status;

@XmlPath("status[2]")
private Status statusDetail;
```

Aquí puedes encontrar mas información
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts005.htm

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono tal y como me lo pusiste en el ejemplo : ).